# What happens to data members in Threading in Java?

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain what happens to data members while threading? I mean in the below code the output is as I wanted i.e thread name with its corresponding number.However if I pass the reference of 1 thread to all the other threads the thread name varies but the number 50 is printed for all the thread names.Why does this happen?

```
class Thread3 implements Runnable
{
int x;

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ x);

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){ }
        }   

    }
}
public class RunThread3 {

public static void main(String s[])
{
Thread3 t1=new Thread3();
t1.x=50;
Thread tt1=new Thread(t1,"thread1");
tt1.start();

Thread3 t2=new Thread3();
t2.x=100;
Thread tt2=new Thread(t2,"thread2");
tt2.start();

Thread3 t3=new Thread3();
t3.x=150;
Thread tt3=new Thread(t3,"thread3");
tt3.start();

for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){ }
        }   

}
}
```

Here reference of 1 thread passed to all others

```
class Thread3 implements Runnable
{
int x;

    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ x);

            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){ }
        }   

    }
}
public class RunThread3 {

public static void main(String s[])
{
Thread3 t1=new Thread3();
t1.x=50;
Thread tt1=new Thread(t1,"thread1");
tt1.start();

Thread3 t2=new Thread3();
t2.x=100;
Thread tt2=new Thread(t1,"thread2");
tt2.start();

Thread3 t3=new Thread3();
t3.x=150;
Thread tt3=new Thread(t1,"thread3");
tt3.start();

for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e){ }
        }   

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the later code you are passing reference of thread `t1` to all:

```
Thread3 t1=new Thread3();
t1.x=50;
Thread tt1=new Thread(t1,"thread1");
tt1.start();
Thread tt2=new Thread(t1,"thread2");
tt2.start();
Thread tt3=new Thread(t1,"thread3");
tt3.start();
```

This means all thread will be having value of x as 50 and when you execute the code you will get the expected value:

`thread1 50
thread2 50
main
thread3 50
main
thread1 50
thread3 50
thread2 50
thread1 50
main
thread3 50
thread2 50
thread3 50
main
thread2 50
thread1 50
main
thread3 50
thread2 50
thread1 50`

In the former case you are having different threads and they work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is your misunderstanding of threading and classes in java.
In your code you have 2 different entities: java Thread and your custom Runnable class.
Name of thread that you got in your sample is name of java Thread object. Number `x` that you got in your sample is number of your custom Runnable class. Please note: I skipped name of your class - it makes misunderstanding. So if you use only one your custom Runnable object - you'll always got single `x` value.